# I have new information about the same question, which changes the answer. Do I ask a new question or combine them?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

So I asked a question about joining tables together in MySQL. The original question was pretty simple, and I actually managed to answer it myself without realising. Someone came along and confirmed that my attempt worked the way I had originally planned. (The answer was basically "yup it works" with a table of the results)

[Here is the original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/38092329/1)

However, I reviewed the table structure, and realized that the parameters were dependant on a hierarchy, making the original question redundant. I asked a new question, and noted the original question for context, and proceeded with the new question.

[Here is the new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38114439/sql-query-to-join-based-on-heirarchical-data)

Now, after asking the new question, a user stated that since the original problem was not (technically) solved, I should just edit the original. However, another user stated that that action would not be fair on the previous answerer; as it makes his answer redundant.

So what am I to do? Ask a new question, or edit the old?

Comment: The consensus on Meta has always been to not make existing answers invalid by editing the question. If your edits make the pre-existing answer wrong then it should be a new question instead.

Comment: Who wants to bet that the new question gets marked as a duplicate to the old question for being too similar?

Comment: Ask a new question linking to the old.

Answer (score 4):

You should always aim to ask *perfect question* (the one which is short, clear, understandable, can't be understood wrongly, have all requirements listed so that the answer given to question will be immediately useful for you)... but life is not like that.

If you do a mistake in requirements that makes question **very** different then simply ask another one. Add link to original question (to avoid false-positive duplicate flags and angry comments) and clearly explain why you need a new answer (what is different, why answers for original question are not helpful, etc.).

You can add comments to answers to clarify why answer is not useful for you. Many people are ok with that and will edit their question to fulfill those (if they are able ofc). **If someone tries to answer a broad question, then it's his fault for understanding question wrong**.

However, even those answers what are invalid after clarification (in comments) are **still useful**. Because later people may find your original question and those answers can help them. Upvote helpful to you ones or those what seems to be a good answer to the original question you asked. Accept the one which solves your problem or help you the most. Post your own answer if it's different from existing.